# What should be an optimal team (in terms of roles) to write a big enterprise nice-quality framework?

Tags: team, frameworks, development

I have a set of questions that bothering me, hopefully someone will be able to answer them here:

- What should be an optimal team (in terms of roles) to write a big enterprise nice-quality framework?
- What big frameworks could act as a good references in terms of documentation, architecture, quality of implementation etc?
- What is your assumptions about size of teams that developed this frameworks?

Looking forward for answers. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable. Everything is subjective.

Comment: It all depends on the context, but it would still be interesting to hear stories.

Comment: I totally agree that there is no an ultimate answer, however it would be nice to hear what is the framework teams organizations in big companies. It is also interesting to see what roles are vital, what not. Could be vision regarding the framework architecture be shared or it should be one visionary that holds a sacred knowledge? etc

Comment: When considering the "optimal team", it may be helpful to read the Mythical Man Month - in particular the chapter on the Surgical Team (though Passing The Word is useful too... and all the rest of the book too).

Answer (score 5):

**DO NOT BEGIN A PROJECT BY WRITING A FRAMEWORK**

[Useful frameworks are seldom or never written from scratch.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102702/does-agile-development-need-a-framework-in-place-first/102754#102754)  Useful frameworks are factored out of working applications and refined by attempts to use them in new applications.  Rinse and repeat a half-dozen times and you may have something worthwhile.